# Subsetting 1000 random loci from vcf/genind file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to subset 1000 loci from a vcf or genind files however I am unable to do so. Is there a way to subset 1000 randomly selected loci from a vcf or genind file in R? Example of my code below...

### Load libraries and Get Data

```
library(OutFLANK)
library(SNPRelate)
library(dartR)
library(vcfR)
library(poppr)
library(hierfstat)
library(reshape2)

data(vcfR_example) #get the data
vcfd = vcfR2genind(vcf) #convert vcf file to genind
vcfd <- vcfd[,c(sample(1:5083, 1000, replace=T))] #subset 1000 loci ???
pop(vcfd) <- as.factor(c("5", "5", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", 
                               "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "9", "9", "9")) #assign populations
```

#### DOES NOT WORK

```
basic_vcfd = basic.stats(vcfd, diploid = TRUE) #compute basic.stats
Error in rep(lab, vec) : invalid 'times' argument
```

### Check subsetted Genind object for loci number

```
/// GENIND OBJECT /////////

 // 18 individuals; 836 loci; 1,000 alleles; size: 480 Kb

 // Basic content
   @tab:  18 x 1000 matrix of allele counts
   @loc.n.all: number of alleles per locus (range: 1-4)
   @loc.fac: locus factor for the 1000 columns of @tab
   @all.names: list of allele names for each locus
   @ploidy: ploidy of each individual  (range: 2-2)
   @type:  codom
   @call: .local(x = x, i = i, j = j, drop = drop)

 // Optional content
   - empty -
```

This code does not work. You can see above that there are 836 loci however I need 1000. I need the 1000 loci to calculate the basic.stats function. Looking for a solution.

Comment: You need to give us an example of your current data and expected result.

Comment: @gaut I have added most if not all of the requested information.

Comment: are you sure you have an OS issue? I can't install your first package.

Comment: I believe that we need to use devtools::install_github("whitlock/OutFLANK"). The OS issue is that I need OSX or Linux to run a separate package that could do what I needed. However, figuring a method in R is still the best option.

Comment: What OS are you running? You can use Windows 10 WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) to compile and run Stacks. Instructions here: https://rpubs.com/mendiomi/869617

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't working for me.

Comment: since you can't use these packages, try to give us an example of your original data and expected results, without using them.

Comment: All of the potential examples is supplied in this question. I am solely looking for an answer for the original question. I can use the r packages. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: It is hard to tell without data, but maybe you are sampling columns instead of rows. Try `vcfd[c(sample(1:5083, 1000, replace=T)), ]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vcfd[loc=sample(nLoc(vcfd), 1000, replace=F)]
```

This worked!

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
locs = locNames(vcfd)[1:1000]
new_vcfd = vcfd[loc = locs]
```

It does indeed return a genuine object with exactly 1,000 loci.

Comment: I now realise you wanted random loci, sorry! But just a very small change to my code will still make it work!